# MLE Asymptotic Theorem

Tags: self-study

Statement: if $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of some parameter $\theta$ then asymptotically $\hat{\theta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, I_\theta^{-1}),$ where $I_\theta$ is the fisher information matrix.

My question is, what if $\hat{\theta}$ is a biased estimator of $\theta$? Surely $\mu$ will not be $\theta$ then.

Comment: Please see [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+estimator+bias*) for more about this topic.

Comment: Why would you say that surely it would not be? Biased estimators are in some cases asymptotically unbiased.